# How to use if else statements and dialog box?

Tags: java, ios, eclipse, if-statement, dialog

I have a school assignment which needs me to make a ticketing system for a theatre. So the conditions is that for Monday - Thursday, people with age under 10 will be free of charge, 10-65 will have to pay RM10 and over 65 will also be free of charge. For Friday - Sunday, age under 10 will have to pay RM10, 10-65 pay RM20 and over 65 pay RM10.

I tried putting in dialog box and I got this so far:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class NewTicketSystem {

public static final String [] days = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday",
        "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Input Dialog Example 3");
    String Day = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, 
        "Which day do you want to choose?",
        "Day",
        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, 
        null, 
        days, 
        days[0]);

    System.out.printf("Chosen day is %s.\n", Day);

    JFrame frames = new JFrame("InputDialog Example #1");


    String UserAge = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frames, "What is your age?");

    System.out.printf("Your age is '%s'.\n", UserAge);

     System.exit(0);


    }

}
```

My problem now is, how do I put in the conditions into the coding? I've tried searching online but still couldn't understand. Please explain in simple terms if possible.

And thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int price;

if (Day.equals("Monday") || Day.equals("Tuesday") || Day.equals("Wednesday") || Day.equals("Thursday")) { //Monday - Thursday
    if (UserAge >= 10 && UserAge <=65) //10-65
        price = 10;
    else //Under 10 and Above 65
        price = 0;
} else { //Friday - Sunday
     if (UserAge >= 10 && UserAge <=65) //10-65
         price = 20;
     else //Under 10 and Above 65
         price = 10;
}
```

Comment: Oh alright missed out 1 bracket there and it's working now!

Comment: I added the missing bracket into the code. Sorry for my careless mistake...